# Why do I have to state parameter type when assigning a delegate function to a delegate variable?

Tags: c#, types, delegates

Say I have a delegate like this.

```
namespace somedelegatesb1  {
    class Program  {
        delegate int Abc(int a);
        static void Main(string[] args)  {
            Abc abc = delegate(int e) {  
              return 0; 
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Why is it that I have to write the parameter int e, here

```
Abc abc = delegate(int e) {  
                  return 0; 
                };
```

Why can't I write

```
Abc abc = delegate(e) {  
                  return 0; 
          };
```

It won't compile, but isn't it 'obvious' that it would be int e?  what else would it be?   It's impossible to be anything other than int e, since the delegate requires int e.

And suppose i'm not using a parameter, i.e. the function will take a parameter but say it won't use the variable. then it's completely pointless. Why can't I write

```
Abc abc = delegate {  
                  return 0; 
          };
```

And even if I was using a parameter.. the variable name is not necessarily that relevant for example in javascript you can say arguments[0]. So why not allow `Abc abc = delegate {...};`

I know C# is strictly typed, but i'm not sugggesting changing the type when writing the type after delegate. And i'm not suggesting c# allow passing in more or less parameters than have been defined. It's just superfluous to write the type. Even the variable name in some cases isn't necessary e.g. if not using it, though one would normally use it so I can see why they might mandate that,  but certainly the type here is absolutely unnececessary and pointless. So why does C# seem to require it?

Comment: Because the language specification for anonymous methods says you have to.  It can not be argued with.  Use a lambda expression instead.

Comment: the type inference in C# is quite stupid (as you've noticed) - if you want something better use F# ;) (and this is only the beginning - but quite the end on .net ATM)

Comment: @HansPassant a lambda is a anonymous method (it just get special treatment/syntax in C# - you can use it with or without stating the types (most of the time))

Comment: If you dont want to specifiy your parameters in detail... use lambda instead.

Comment: Your last example is actually legal code: `Abc abc = delegate { return 0; };` (C# 6.0)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen interesting, thanks.. in which case suppose an argument is passed.. then can the body of the delegate refer to the argument given no variable name?

Comment: No, it cannot refer to arguments without giving them a name.